# slick - creating schema with optional blob getting ERROR: type "lo" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, slick

I am using Play Evaluation with postgreSQL and slick

This is the Model :

```
case class Employee(id: Int,first:String,last:String,title:String,pic: Option[Blob])
class Employees(tag:Tag) extends Table[Employee](tag,"EMPLOYEES"){
  def id = column[Int]("ID",O.PrimaryKey, O.NotNull)
  def first = column[String]("LAST", O.NotNull)
  def last = column[String]("LAST", O.NotNull)
  def title = column[String]("TITLE")
  def pic = column[Blob]("PICTURE",O.Nullable)
  override def * = (id,first,last,title,pic.?)<> (Employee.tupled,Employee.unapply)
}
```

But I am getting this

> ERROR: type "lo" does not exist

the sql created shows :

```
create table "EMPLOYEES" ("ID" INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"LAST" VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,"TITLE" VARCHAR(254) NOT NULL,"PICTURE" lo);
```

where is this "lo" type came from and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Hi @igx, what is the data type of your PICTURE column in your EMPLOYEES table at sql side?

Comment: Not sure that I understood waht you meant. The sql side is created by play evaluation

Comment: I am using the same thing and it should be bytea instead of lo. can you please try configure the setting mentioned in the link. http://www.z-space.com/kb/Article.aspx?ID=10275

Answer (score 0):

can you please put below two implicit method in your class Employees and try?

```
private implicit def blob2Bytes(blob: java.sql.Blob): Array[Byte] = {
  if (blob.length == 0)
    return Array[Byte]()
  val r = blob.getBytes(1, blob.length.toInt)
  blob.free
  r
}

private implicit def bytes2Blob(bytes: Array[Byte]) = {
  new SerialBlob(bytes)
}
```

Comment: Thanks , But that didn't help ... same result